# Nikon D750 display in the viewfinder is not working

Tags: autofocus, viewfinder, display, nikon-d750

I dropped my Nikon d750 off a low shelf.  There is not visible damage.  However, the viewfinder stopped displaying info.  Any thoughts or suggestions?  Has anyone ever encountered this?  Thanks.

Comment: if lucky, loose connector inside. If not, broken circuit inside. Only the Nikon service center can tell. Also, if you had a big/heavy lens attached, check that the mount isn't even so slightly bent.

Comment: Thank you.  I had on a 24-70 2.8.  I also have a 70-200mm 2.8vr.  The problem is with both lens.

Comment: Bent mount would be extra damage (and likely require the body to be replaced). More likely to happen if there was a heavy lens attached during the fall.